# Constraints error during partitions Drop

Tags: oracle

When i am trying to drop partitions in oracle i am facing the below mentioned error.

Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-02266 -  "unique/primary keys in table referenced by enabled foreign keys"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to truncate a table with unique or
           primary keys referenced by foreign keys enabled in another table.
           Other operations not allowed are dropping/truncating a partition of a
           partitioned table or an ALTER TABLE EXCHANGE PARTITION.
*Action:   Before performing the above operations the table, disable the
           foreign key constraints in other tables. You can see what
           constraints are referencing a table by issuing the following
           command:
           SELECT * FROM USER_CONSTRAINTS WHERE TABLE_NAME = "tabnam";

i have few system constraints and few developed by me so do i need to disable the system constraints also to drop partitions, attached is the screenshot of constraints.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epSUi.jpg)

Comment: The issue, as Oracle clearly says, is with _unique or primary keys referenced by foreign keys enabled in another table_, not `NOT NULL` constraints. Also, please [not  screenshots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: do i need to disable the primary key constraints and what if another table have foreign key constraints referring to this table do i need to disable that also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe an example will clarify. Say I have a `master` table, partitioned, and a `detail` table that references `master` with a FK:

```
SQL> create table master(col1 number, part number)
  2  partition by list(part) (
  3      partition p0 values (0),
  4      partition p1 values (1),
  5      partition p2 values (2)
  6  );

Table created.

SQL> alter table master add constraint master_pk primary key ( col1, part);

Table altered.

SQL> create table detail(col1 number, part number, col2 varchar2(100));

Table created.

SQL> alter table detail add constraint master_detail_fk foreign key ( col1, part) references master ( col1, part);

Table altered.
```

I insert some rows in both tables, according to the FK constraint:

```
SQL> insert into master (col1, part) select level, mod(level, 3) from dual connect by level < 10;

9 rows created.

SQL> insert into detail (col1, part, col2) select level, mod(level, 3), 'something' from dual connect by level < 10;

9 rows created.
```

Now I try to drop a partition in the master:

```
SQL> alter table master drop partition p1;
alter table master drop partition p1
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02266: unique/primary keys in table referenced by enabled foreign keys
```

I need to handle the FK before dropping:

```
SQL> alter table detail disable constraint master_detail_fk ;

Table altered.

SQL> alter table master drop partition p1;

Table altered.
```

Of course, if I dropped referenced rows, the constraint will not be validated:

```
SQL> alter table detail enable validate constraint master_detail_fk ;
alter table detail enable validate constraint master_detail_fk
                                              *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02298: cannot validate (SIUCREDITO.MASTER_DETAIL_FK) - parent keys not
found

SQL> alter table detail enable novalidate constraint master_detail_fk ;

Table altered.

SQL>
```